# WSAPoll on named fd :: need suggestions how to rewrite it

Tags: c, sockets, posix, winsock, winsock2

I've some `POSIX`**`C`** code that I'm porting to windows (WinSocks 2.2) and I'm having problems with MS implementation of (not only) `poll()`.

I have some experience with POSIX `sockets`, but I'm quite new to WinSock2, I haven't found any helpful leads on MSDN, so I ask here: ***"How to make equivalent behaviour to this sample code on windows?"***

```
static int connect_to_addr(char *address, char *port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *addr;
    int fd;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;

    if (getaddrinfo(address, port, &hints, &addr) != 0) return -1;

    fd = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    if (fd < 0) return -1;

    if (connect(fd, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) < 0) return -1;

    freeaddrinfo(addr);
    return fd;
}
```

Function `connect_to_addr()` is just for demonstration what `fd` on second field looks like.

```
WSAStartup(...)
...
pollfd cinfd[2];
fds[0].fd = _fileno(stdin); //THIS is probably not supported on win32 
fds[0].events = POLLIN;
fds[1].fd = f_connect(some_addr, some_port); //OK
fds[1].events = POLLIN;

while (1) {
    res = WSAPoll(fds, 2, -1); //returns 1

    if (fds[0].revents & (POLLIN | POLLHUP)) { //fds[0].revents == POLLNVAL  !! problem
        char buf[1024];
        int n, w, i;
        n = read(fds[0].fd, buf, 1024);
        ...
    }

    if (fds[1].revents & POLLIN) {
        char buf[1024];
        int n, w, i;
        n = recv(fds[1].fd, buf, 1024, 0);
        ...
    }
}
```

How to implement this common idiom under WinSocks? Thanks for suggestions.

Better yet, WSAPoll() is in ws2_32.dll since Vista; how to make it work under XP?

Comment: [This](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have better to use WaitForMultipleObjects() for waiting stdin/sock.

```
HANDLE h[2];
h[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
h[1] = sock;

while (1) {
    DWORD ret;
    ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, FALSE, 0 /* wait value you want */);

    if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        // munipulating stdin.
    }
    if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) {
        // munipulating sock.
        // then call recv.
    }
}
```