# stdin file descriptor never ready on POLLIN event

Tags: c, windows, select, stdin

I have a C source code that I intend to port from Linux to Windows. After updating the 'poll' function to 'WSAPoll,' I notice that 'revents' on 'stdin' never becomes ready, causing 'WSAPoll' to block the code due to the absence of ready file descriptors.

How can I ensure that 'stdin' becomes ready in this context?

the client code:

```c
static void start_event_loop(struct client_ctx *cl_ctx)
{
    int nr_ready;

    cl_ctx->need_reload_prompt = true;
    while (1) {
        if (cl_ctx->need_reload_prompt) {
            printf(PLACE_HOLDER);
            fflush(stdout);
            cl_ctx->need_reload_prompt = false;
        }

        #ifndef __WIN32
        nr_ready = poll(cl_ctx->fds, 2, -1);
        #else
        nr_ready = WSAPoll(cl_ctx->fds, 2, -1);
        #endif
        if (nr_ready < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;

            perror("poll");
            break;
        }

        if (handle_events(cl_ctx) < 0)
            break;
    }
}

static int initialize_ctx(struct client_ctx *cl_ctx)
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
        printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else
        printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");
    #endif

    cl_ctx->tcp_fd = connect_server();
    if (cl_ctx->tcp_fd < 0)
        return -1;

    printf("Successfuly connected to %s:%d\n", SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_PORT);

    cl_ctx->fds[0].fd = cl_ctx->tcp_fd;
    cl_ctx->fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    cl_ctx->fds[1].fd = _fileno(stdin);
    cl_ctx->fds[1].events = POLLRDNORM;

    cl_ctx->recv_len = 0;
    memset(&cl_ctx->pkt, 0, sizeof(cl_ctx->pkt));

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The current behavior with 'WSAPoll' is preventing me from inputting or typing anything into 'stdin' because it's blocking the code while waiting for a ready file descriptor.

EDIT2: I recently transitioned from using WSAPoll to WaitForMultipleObjects, but I've encountered an unusual issue. The TCP socket file descriptor never seems to trigger as expected. I've monitored the traffic using Wireshark and confirmed that the packets are being sent from the server to the client. However, in the client program, WaitForMultipleObjects doesn't return the index where the socket file descriptor is stored; instead, it returns the stdin file descriptor. Any insights into what might be causing this unexpected behavior?

The 8787 is server port and the others are client port:
[image: wireshark]

The complete source code is available in [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Reyuki-san/chat_app).

Comment: Err, type something into the terminal? Provide an input on `stdin`? And explain to us what `stdin` has to do with networling?

Comment: Silly question: Why use `WSAPoll()`? stdin is not a socket, so I'd say that is the wrong API and I'd expect some errors to be emitted. Do you check for errors properly? Instead, I'd use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` instead. All that said, your Q definitely lacks a [mcve], including how you run the compiled code.

Comment: (almost exact!) dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420653/wsapoll-on-named-fd-need-suggestions-how-to-rewrite-it

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt previously I use poll to make the program able to receive message while the program waiting for user input

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 UlrichEckhardt thanks for the advice, I willl take a look on WaitForMultipleObjects

Comment: Didn't you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll)? It's pretty clear `WSAPoll()` only works with sockets.

Comment: You need to use WSAEventSelect() and WSAEnumNetworkEvents() when dealing with sockets.

Comment: @Luke but Ulrich mentioned stdin isn't a socket. I'm puzzled why there are many Windows API alternatives for similar use cases :(

Comment: You need to use WSAEventSelect() to choose what socket events you're interested in then use WaitForMultipleObjects() to wait for something to happen with the socket or STD_INPUT_HANDLE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works, but the stdin event is signaled as soon as the user starts typing. Meanwhile, in Linux, the stdin event is only flagged as ready when the user hit 'Enter'.

Do you have any ideas on how to mimic the Linux behavior on Windows? because the current behavior is blocking the program on fgets instead of waiting on WaitForMultipleObjects

Comment: I tried to figure out how to control the ready state of stdin and read the following reference: [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955617/win32-read-from-stdin-with-timeout), but I still could not find the proper way; maybe the remaining option is using a thread?